# Modify java.library.path for wildfly 8.2.0

Tags: java, windows, dll, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have a set of dlls which need to be there in `java.library.path` for `Wildfly 8.2.0`. My problem is, there are some older versions of same DLLs present in `system32` (Windows system folder). Whenever I try to start Wildfly (by using standalone.bat), it is picking up `system32` folder on priority and loading older version of DLLs hence failing the application.

To avoid this, I think I need to set my DLLs folder BEFORE `system32` in `java.library.path`. So I tried following things:

1. Pass jvm param to standalone.bat. Something like:

> ```
> SET PATH=D:\mydlls;%PATH%;
> call standalone.bat -Djava.library.path=%PATH%
> ```

2. Set JAVA_OPTS.

> ```
> SET JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.library.path=%PATH% %JAVA_OPTS%;
> call standalone.bat
> ```

None of these seem to work since Wildfly still loads older version of DLL from `system32` directory. What's wrong in this? Is there any way to achieve this?